# Alternative to background-size using IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on this: http://www.shbarcelona.es/whoweare/debug

In Firefox and Chrome all works fine but the problem comes in background-size property which is not supported on IE7 and I'm used this property all time.

I've been looking at alternatives on google but any works correctly. Any tips?

Comment: You are talking about which section?

Comment: the grid on the right <div class="grid_staff"> every element on the grid use background-image & background-size. the problem is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

But if you use sprites you can have some issues...

Sources : [AlphaImageLoader Filter @microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Use of AlphaImageLoader is now frowned upon as it slows down pages and can crash some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

PPK shows that it is not supported in IE <9 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/backgrounds-borders/

Paul Irish et al have some say too: http://html5please.com/#background

and I found this polyfill: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill also found http://ianfeather.co.uk/ten-reasons-we-switched-from-an-icon-font-to-svg/ that says that polyfill crashed ie8.